# Unable to delete environment

Tags: advanced-rest-client

When I try to delete an environment, it says 'The list of environments is empty', but there are 5 environments in the list, how can I successfully delete one of them?

Comment: Did you try to restart the app?

Comment: And is it Chrome app or desktop app?

Comment: Desktop app and yes restarted several times